# Minimax fatalistic when choosing a move

Tags: minimax

I have created a minimax function that determines the best possible move from a game state. Currently, it plays great except that it thinks that the opponent will always perfectly resulting in bad moves starting from gamestates (a possible board) like this:

```
X _ _
_ O _
_ _ _
```

Computer think that no matter what he does it will result in a tie, because the opponent will play perfectly. So he chooses the first move make a tie, resulting in this board:

```
X X _
_ O _ 
_ _ _
```

Where this move would've been better, when playing against a human opponent who makes mistakes.

```
X _ _ 
_ O _
_ _ X
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You realize that perfect game play in Tic-Tac-Toe *does* always result in a tie, right?

Comment: I know. But I am pitting minimax against a real opponent, and people make mistakes

Comment: What happens when the computer goes second?

Comment: It always goes in the center.